# How to Add Values of Some Specified Column in SSRS

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I have a report Which having 10 column in which 5 or more column name is score i want to add all Score Column value into a Total Score Column. how can we do this ?

i want to write a expression or anything which can add only Score Column value.

Comment: Do you have a column roup that is creating the multiple columns the the name score? Have you tried adding a column outside of the column group and then doing a sum using the dataset as the group in the sum function?

Comment: i am doing same thing but not with dataset it is Report items field.Score is based on some other calculation it is not derived from database